# Unable to place the order

Tags: magento-1.9, database, paypal-express, ce-1.9.2.4, place-order

Recently I switched Magento version from 1.6 to 1.9.2.4  since I am unable to place order payment method  by paypal.

[image]

If I place order by payment method by cash on delivery it's working well

Error log I found this below:

> 2016-12-06T13:36:26+00:00 ERR (3):
>   exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000001' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID'' in lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
>   Stack trace:

Comment: thanks every one i got solution.
issue was  invoice are not generating in table 'eav_entity_store' i create an manually now its working